# Get average values in some specific range based on spatial analysis with QGIS

Tags: geospatial, qgis

I'm working on QGIS to compute average values attached to polygons
around a line.

What I'd like to do is compute the average values of polygon data within a user defined range from a line.

How would I go about doing this?

I have attached a picture below for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There should be a couple ways of doing this. The easiest *might* be the answer in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86747/how-to-select-polygons-by-distance-to-a-single-polygon-in-another-layer), and then using the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/getting-tabular-statistics-from-table-using-qgis).

But, you should be able to do this with a little bit of python. I've written a little script that uses just one layer (a point layer that finds the average of points within a certain radius, it averages a field named 'cost'):

```
# get selected feature
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.selectedFeatures()

# Buffer the feature 10 layer units
buffer = features[0].geometry().buffer(10,-1)

# Will hold features intersecting buffer
inBuffer = []

# get selected features
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    if (feature.geometry().intersects(buffer)):
        inBuffer.append(feature)

# for calculating the average
total = 0
number = 0

# Sum the features that intersect the buffer of the selection:
field = layer.fieldNameIndex('cost')
for feature in inBuffer:
    total += (feature['cost'])
    number += 1

#Get the average
average = float(total / number)

print (average)
```

*This takes only the first selected feature (features[0]) and applies the search radius to that, this limitation is irrelevant if you only select on feature in the active layer*

The code above can be compressed a fair bit, but I thought I'd break it out a little more. Especially as my python is fairly limited.

To find an average in a second layer based on the selection in a first layer, you could modify this slightly by grabbing all layers:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()
```

then using `layers[0]`, `layers[1]` (or `layers[i]`) in place of layer at the appropriate places, something like:

`features = layer.selectedFeatures()` to `features = layers[0].selectedFeatures()`

for the source feature, and

`for feature in layer.getFeatures():` to `for feature in layers[1].getFeatures()`

and

`field = layer.fieldNameIndex('fieldname')` to `field = layers[1].fieldNameIndex('fieldname')`

for the target feature (the one being averaged).

Hopefully the code I have posted is easy enough to apply. I would probably ensure that both layers use the same SRS to avoid any issues with the intersection, and remember that the buffer units are in the units of that SRS.